# trying to upload multiple files(with any extensions) into mysql databse using servlet + jsp + mysql

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, netbeans-8

I am new with Servlet and JSP and I am trying to upload multiple files into MySQL database but Only one file is storing into database. I have added (multiple="multiple" while selecting files) in index.jsp page. but stores only one file which I select at first. I don't know what changes I have to do into my java class(UploadServletClass.java). please help me with this. I am using netbeans 8.2, apache tomcat 8, xampp MySQL. My code uploads only one file into MySQL database successfully. but I want to upload multiple files simultaneously. Thanks in advance :)

This is my index.jsp page

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document Management System</title>
    <style>
      h1 {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
      }
      
      body {
        background-image: url("background.png");
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <center>
      <form action="UploadServletClass" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <center>
          <h1>Welcome to Document Management System...</h1>
        </center>
        <table width="400px" align="center" border="2" bordercolor="#33CCFF">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="firstname">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="lastname">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Division</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="division">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Reporting Unit</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="reportingunit">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Document Number</td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" required="" name="documentnumber">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Document Name</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="documentname">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Document Uploader</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="documentuploader">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Document Owner</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" required="" name="documentowner">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Document Type</td>
            <td>
              <select name="Document_Type">

                <option value="Agreement">Agreement</option>
                <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                <option value="PO">PO</option>
                <option value="Invoice">Invoice</option>
                <option value="COA">COA</option>
                <option value="Lease Deed">Lease Deed</option>
                <option value="AMC">AMC</option>

              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <br><br>
          <tr>
            <td>Document Category</td>
            <td>
              <select name="Document_Category">
                <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
                <option value="Internal">Internal</option>

              </select>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <br><br>


          <tr>
            <td>Select File</td>
            <td>
              <input type="file" required="" name="file" id="file" multiple="multiple">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <br><a href="filelist.jsp">View List</a>
    </center>
  </body>

  </html>
```

This is my UploadServletClass.java

```js
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        try{
            out = response.getWriter();
            session = request.getSession(false);
            String folderName = "resources";
            //String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + folderName;
            String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + folderName;
            File dir = new File(uploadPath);
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            
            Part filepart = request.getPart("file");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String fileName = filepart.getSubmittedFileName();
            String path = folderName + File.separator + fileName;
            Timestamp added_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String div = request.getParameter("division");                          //textbox value of division field
            String repunit = request.getParameter("reportingunit");                 //textbox value of reportingunit field
            int docnum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("documentnumber"));  ///textbox value of documentnumber field
            String docName = request.getParameter("documentname");                  //textbox value of documentname field
            String docUploader = request.getParameter("documentuploader");          //textbox value of documentuploader field
            String docOwner = request.getParameter("documentowner");                //textbox value of documentowner field
            String docType = request.getParameter("Document_Type");                 //textbox value of Document_Type field
            String docCategory = request.getParameter("Document_Category");         //textbox value of Document_Category field
            
            System.out.println("filename:" +fileName);
            System.out.println("path:" +uploadPath);
            System.out.println("Name:" +firstName);
            InputStream ins = filepart.getInputStream();
            Files.copy(ins, Paths.get(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            try {
                con = DB.getConnection();
                System.out.println("connection done");
                String sql = "insert into newfiles(firstname,lastname,filename,path,division,reportingunit,documentnumber,documentname,documentuploader,documentowner,documenttype,documentcategory,added_date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; //inserting all values into database
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, firstName);
                ps.setString(2, lastName);
                ps.setString(3, fileName);
                ps.setString(4, path);
                ps.setString(5, div);           //index specifies the respective parameter in the query
                ps.setString(6, repunit);
                ps.setInt(7, docnum);
                ps.setString(8,docName);
                ps.setString(9, docUploader);
                ps.setString(10, docOwner);
                ps.setString(11,docType);
                ps.setString(12, docCategory);
                ps.setTimestamp(13, added_date);
                int status = ps.executeUpdate();
                if(status > 0){
                        session.setAttribute("filename", fileName);
                        String msg = "" + fileName + "  File Uploaded Successfully...";
                        request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/process.jsp");
                        rd.forward(request,response);
                        System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
                        System.out.println("Uploaded Path:" +uploadPath);
                        
                        
                        
                }
            } catch(SQLException e){
                out.println("Exception:" +e);
                System.out.println("Exception1:" +e);
                
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(ps != null){
                        ps.close();
                    }
                    if(con != null){
                        con.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e){
                    out.println(e);
                }
            }
          
        
            
        } catch(IOException | ServletException e){
            out.println("Exception:" +e);
            System.out.println("Exception2:" +e);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://learningprogramming.net/java/jsp-servlet/multiple-file-upload-in-jsp-servlet/ - especially the _Create Helpers_ section.

Comment: looks like you're not even parsing the file parts..... is your form multipart enabled? Did you specifiy multipart for the servlet also? You need to post all relevant code.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte edited index.jsp file.

Comment: someone please help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Add this notation to your Servlet @MultipartConfig

```
@WebServlet(name = "test", urlPatterns = { "/test" })
@MultipartConfig
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
//code
}
```

And to get all files use this in your doPost:

```
Collection<Part> fileparts = request.getParts();
```

Look here for a full example and more options you can use/change: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html

Comment: hey buddy, I have added these lines into my UploadServletClass.java file. String fileName = filepart.getSubmittedFileName();
            List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part->"file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for(Part filePart: fileParts){
                fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
                filePart.write(uploadPath+File.separator+fileName);
            }                        there is no error but it is not working

Comment: After adding above code of List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part)………….. into UploadServletClass.java file. When I try to upload multiple files then all are going to "resources"(resources folder is menstioned in above UploadServletClass.java class) folder successfully but the record is not showing into MySQL database. why? please help me regarding this . Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I suppose you are using the for-loop to send all parts to the database, right? You should loop all parts in the Collection<Part> fileparts and do your insert. In your code you are doing only one insert.